# Bug in svindd.ist?

Tags: hyperref, sv-classes

Let us consider Springer's `svmono` class together with the file `svindd.ist` supposed to be used by makeindex; cf. [Springer's guidelines](https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/manuscript-preparation/5636), which reference the [templates](https://resource-cms.springernature.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/20566/data/v3).  Let us compile the input

```
\documentclass{svmono}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{none}%%% Makes sure that if we drop "-s svindd.ist", the hyperlinks point where they should point.
\title{Book's title}
\maketitle
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter's title}
\lipsum[1-2]
keyword\index{keyword}
\lipsum[1-2]\section{Section's title}keyword\index{keyword}%%% culprit line
\printindex
\end{document}
```

stored in `book.tex` with the standard loop:

```
pdflatex book && makeindex -s svindd.ist book && pdflatex book
```

(Remark: of course, the above is only a MWE; a real book uses way more class options, packages, and bibtex in addition.)

What we see on the last page of the output PDF is the index, in which two references are merged into one:

[image: last page of the output]

Clicking on the red box gets you to the title page instead of the keyword definitions. In the log you see the warning:

`name{page.1,\\relax\040\\hskip\0400.2em\\ignorespaces\0402} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one`

One can have two workarounds:

- remove the culprit line in the source (but you really want to have both pages in the index),
- drop `-s svindd.ist` (but that's what German books are supposed to use).

***Now, are we using Springer's class files in a wrong way or is `svindd.ist` erroneous?***

The contents of svindd.ist is as follows:

```
quote '+'
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\bf "
heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak%\n \\indexspace\\nopagebreak%"
delim_0 "\\idxquad "
delim_1 "\\idxquad "
delim_2 "\\idxquad "
delim_n ",\\,"
```

Comment: What do you expect if you have `\pagenumbering{none}`??!!

Comment: Please do not link directly to ZIP files!!

Comment: Deleted the files which got downloaded. I don't trust ZIPs from unknown sources. https://resource-cms.springernature.com/ is non-site which just provides the standard Apache installation place holder. No idea whether this has anything actually to do with Springer or not.

Comment: Presumably, `\mainmatter` may include `\pagenumbering{arabic}`, but I don't have the `.cls` to check. So maybe that isn't a problem, though `\pagenumbering{none}` is still not the right way to go.

Comment: I have no idea whether TeX SE has such a policy and never claimed otherwise. **I** have a policy of avoiding such links, where possible, or deleting downloads immediately, otherwise. Many people are suspicious of such links unless posted by trusted sources. Hence, relying on them effectively reduces the pool of potential helpers. It doesn't matter two hoots what TeX SE says about it: you still need individual members to do the helping. (I don't care if you post a direct link so long as it is labelled and you also give me another way to get the download or, better, the relevant file.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hyerrref is trying to split the page list up on `,` (comma-space) but `svindd.ist` makes the list be separated by `,\,` (comma-thinspace) so you need to adjust the splitting loop, replacing  by `\,`

```
\documentclass{svmono}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\@commahyperpage#1{\@@commahyperpage#1,\,,\\}
\def\@@commahyperpage#1,\,#2,#3\\{%
  \ifx\\#2\\%
    \HyInd@pagelink{#1}%
  \else
    \HyInd@pagelink{#1},\,\HyInd@pagelink{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{none}
\title{Book's title}
\maketitle
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter's title}
\lipsum[1-2]
keyword\index{keyword}
\lipsum[1-2]\section{Section's title}keyword\index{keyword}%%% culprit line
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: @MdAyquassar hyperref can not know every possible definition by every possible package, the springer class should do this for its German option

Comment: @MdAyquassar the refguide.pdf that is in the zip has a contact email address on page 2